# Powershell - Copy all items from a known subfolder and exclude everything else

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to copy over some PDFs that are nested inside of a directory.

Here is the structure. There are about 100 directories similar to the structure below

Top Folder

- ParentFolder1

  - Subfolder1
  - Subfolder2
- ParentFolder2

  - Subfolder1
  - Subfolder2

What I'm trying to do is copy everything out of `Subfolder1` in each `ParentFolder`. Subfolder1 has the same name in every `ParentFolder`.

I can get all of the files using this command

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Temp\Powershell' -Recurse -Include *.pdf
```

But when I tell it to copy the files over with this command

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Temp\Powershell' -Recurse -Include *.pdf
ForEach-Object {Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination 'C:\Temp\Destination'}
```

It gives me this error

```
Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:2 char:27
+ ForEach-Object {Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination 'C:\Temp\Destinati ...
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

I feel like I'm close, but I want to exclude any directories that aren't named `Subfolder1` and copy all of `Subfolder1` content recursively. I've tried adding in the folder name in the `-Include` statement but was unsuccessful.

**EDIT**
With the help of Tomalak, I was able to figure out my issue plus filter it to only look at `Subfolder1` through each `ParentFolder`

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Temp\Powershell' -Recurse -Include *.pdf 
| Where-Object {$_.PSParentPath -like "*Subfolder1*"} 
| ForEach-Object {Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination 'C:\Temp\Destination'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Copy-Item` takes input from the pipeline, you don't need to use `ForEach-Object` at all.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Temp\Powershell' -Recurse -Include *.pdf | Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\Temp\Destination'
```

But if you want to, you still need to attach it to the pipeline (note the `|`):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Temp\Powershell' -Recurse -Include *.pdf | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination 'C:\Temp\Destination'
}
```

Your code has it on an extra line with no connection to the previous cmdlet at all.

Comment: Excellent. Figured it was something completely simple. With your help I figured the rest of my process out. Thanks!

Comment: @jdids ...although you *still* don't need to use `ForEach-Object` for what you do.